# Setup.cs does not setup Serilog in MvvmCross WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvmcross, serilog

I'm using MvvmCross 7 and WPF Core and I'm trying to use Serilog as logger but I'm must missing something.
I'm following the official guide https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/logging and this my setup.cs:

```
       public Setup(Dispatcher uiThreadDispatcher, IMvxWpfViewPresenter presenter)
    : base(uiThreadDispatcher, presenter)
        {
        }
        protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
        {

            return (IMvxApplication)new ReHUB.Core.App();
        }

        protected override MvxLogProviderType GetDefaultLogProviderType()
        {

            return MvxLogProviderType.Serilog;
        }

        protected override IMvxLogProvider CreateLogProvider()
        {

            string path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "my_log.txt");

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
              .MinimumLevel.Debug()
              .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                      .WriteTo.Logger(config => config
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .WriteTo.File(path))
            .WriteTo.File(path,
                  rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                  outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz} {myCustomVar} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}")
              .CreateLogger();
            return base.CreateLogProvider();
        }
```

Which run with no errors.

My first perplexity is that setup.cs was not already in my project and so I had to create it manually, my second one is that if I put a print in it it will not be printed so I'm not sure if setup.cs is being executed (I guess not).

I then inject it in the constructor of my viewmodel as

```
IMvxLog logger
```

and call it as

```
Log.Logger.Error("Mandrone");
```

But it does not log anything in my my_log.txt.

What I am missing? My first clue is that something changed about setup.cs since MvvmCross 7 but I cant find the answer on internet.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. The solution I've found was to add that line in App.xaml.cs:

```
MvxWpfSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(Dispatcher, MainWindow);
```

That will fire Setup.cs and create a logger.

More information you can find here: [MvvmCross 7 How to setup Serilog in WPF (.net Core 3.1) application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66243881/15058843)

Comment: Thanks! Nice to see somebody using mvvmcross and WPF!
I tried putting that line of code just after "this.RegisterSetupType<MvxWpfSetup<Core.App>>();" in App.xaml.cs but my setup.cs won't be executed and logger won't set up . Did you do something else?

Comment: The thing is you have to put it just before you register your setup. So EnsureSingletonAvailable method goes first and then RegisterSetupType. Reverse the order and that should work.